# Idiom: producing in rapid succession

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm looking for an idiom for “producing multiple (near) identical instances of something in rapid succession”. Ideally it would be colloquial and/or humorous. Do you know any?

Edit: Its intended use is to illustrate in a succinct manner the purpose of some piece of computer software that produces many documents, similar to a mass mailing. In German, we have e.g. “vom Fließband” and “am laufenden Band”, both referring to a conveyor belt in a factory.

Edit 2: I'm thinking about something advertising-like, it would be something like “[product name] – [it gives you] [special type of document] [idiom for ‘many of them in rapid succession’]”

Edit 3: I found [cookie-cutter](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cookie-cutter), which seems nice, but I think its main use is perjorative

Comment: *In his characteristic, machine gun-like staccato, he **fired off** insults at each of the guests at breathtaking speed*. You may mail me my Pulitzer ;)

Comment: *spitting out* such instances

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you would give examples of instances where the idiom would be used.

Comment: *Mail merge* is a fairly dated expression of what you're describing. Add a sample sentence to your question, and use an 'X' or underscore where the word should be. This will give us a better idea of the type of word you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work: ***churning out***

TFD(idioms):

> **[churn out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/churn+out)**
>   *v.* To produce something in an abundant and automatic manner:
>
> Although the chairs look handmade, the company churns them out in a
>   factory.
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs. Copyright © 2005
>   by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton
>   Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.

Comment: I think it sounds too unsophisticated to be used to promote a product, but I think OP is sticking on too many constraints. +1 for matching the requirements of the first paragraph so well.

Comment: +1 I agree w/@EdwinAshworth that your answer matches well OPs “colloquial/humorous” request & also w/his opinion that OP is asking too much of a single idiom. OP could consider spreading-out those constraints evenly over the entire sentence instead of packing them all in 1 idiom at the end, either w/your suggestion or Drew’s: “Our product **continuously churns/spits out** (nearly?) **identical** [documents] **in rapid-fire fashion** [until it’s told to stop].”//“Our product **continuously churns/spits out** [the desired number of] (nearly?) **identical** [documents] **in rapid-fire fashion.**”